# What is better sql or injecting the properties using spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle

I had an interview wherein i was told to read from db and write into a file
in my query i wrote

```
select col1 as aliasOne,
       case when col2 == "someValue" then anotherValue
```

i wrote few of such case statements
but when interviewer saw this he asked me why i choose this approach? to that i said it is faster.
he suggested me to write it in a property file and read it using

```
@ConfigurationProperties("someName")
```

he was of the opinion this is much better and faster.
was he right? I still feel my approach was faster and better

Comment: How you **build** your query string is not relevant to performance if it is the same query in the end. The **execution** of the query is taking the time.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but presumably the whole point of frameworks like Spring is to avoid writing SQL directly by abstracting the schema details and using the interface, unless something really specialised is needed, in which case perhaps a procedure would do a better job anyway. By the way, `col2 == "someValue"` is not valid SQL in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Database calls require network call. So reading from the property file which is deployed along with the application will be slightly faster. 

You look at this article. 
https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

It gives you more flexibility to query as per the environment like (QA/PROD/DEV).

More than performance, it matters of flexibility and ease of maintaining it.